# Create a copy constructor that reverses a stack using a linked list stack implementation

Tags: c++, class, constructor, singly-linked-list, copy-constructor

```
linkList::linkList(linkList const& rhs){
    Node *temp = rhs.top;
    Node *temp_stack = rhs.top;
    while(temp){
        char value = temp->letter;
//        push(value);
        push(temp_stack->letter);
        temp = temp_stack->down;
        temp_stack = temp_stack->down;
//        temp = temp->down;
    }
}

void linkList::push(char c) {
    Node* new_top = new Node(c);
    new_top->down = top;
    top = new_top;
}
```

I have a problem on my copy constructor that when I call it it, it display the link-list in reverse which make sense cause I am pushing it to the back of the new link-list. assuming that my function is working 100 percent and I cant change the function. how would I go about adding it in reverse?
I looked over couple solution in here but no pretty helpful.

Comment: Offhand, the code fine (but why are you iterating with 2 pointers?). But we can't see what your `push()` looks like, so for all we know it is inserting nodes in the reverse order. Please provide a [mcve]. And why are you using names like `top` and `down` instead of more commonlyused names like `head` and `next`?

Comment: @drescherjm no i just have push function which it the data goes to the beginning of the new data

Comment: @drescherjm I know I was thinking if i could iterate through it aging push it back it should work but that didn't work

Comment: Are you implementing a stack or a Linked List? Based on identifiers used you seem to have mixed both together; for a linked list I'd expect member names `head`, `next` and `append` instead of `top`, `down` and `push`...

Comment: @drescherjm its a overall stack the name I changed yes

Comment: @fabian that what I have but what I wanna is to be in reverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters declarations of these two pointers within the function

```
    Node *temp = rhs.top;
    Node *temp_stack = rhs.top;
```

does not make a great sense. They duplicate each other. It is enough to use one pointer to traverse the list `rhs`.

If you want to create a copy of the passed list then the function `push` is not suitable.

You could define the copy constructor the following way.

```
linkList::linkList( linkList const& rhs ) : top( nullptr )
{
    Node **current = &top;

    for ( Node *temp = rhs.top; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->down )
    {
        *current = new Node( temp->letter );
        current = &( *current )->down;
    } 
}
```

I hope that the constructor of the class Node sets the data member down of the created node to `nullptr`.

Comment: Very nice! I think some explanations would help though. Pointer magic :-)

Answer (score 2):

A pragmatic approach could be to just copy the data twice:

```cpp
linkList(linkList const& rhs) {
    linkList tmp;
    // first copy to `tmp`, which will have them in reverse:
    for(Node* curr = rhs.top; curr; curr = curr->down) 
        tmp.push(curr->letter);

    // then populate *this from `tmp` which will then have them
    // in the original order:
    for(Node* curr = tmp.top; curr; curr = curr->down)
        push(curr->letter);
}
```

Comment: that didn't work I am getting the same output  as ```Node *temp = rhs.top; while (temp) { push(temp->letter); temp=temp->down;}```

Comment: @notimportant I don't know what you did, but this works perfectly fine for me. Anyway, Vlad's solution is much more elegant (and cheaper) so I'd go for that one.